# Cannot map input column 'CurrencyDate', to lookup column, 'FullDateAlternateKey', because the data types do not match in AdventureWorksDW2008R2

Tags: ssis, adventureworks

I am attempting to learn SSIS by completing the Microsoft supplied AdventureWOrksDW sample database. I am up to step 6 - Adding and Configuring the Lookup Transformations. I can't seem to map the CurrencyDate to the FullDateALternateKey no matter what data type I change the CurrencyDate field to..

Has anyone been able to complete this and if so how? thanks

[image: When I load Lesson1 I get the following errors..]

Comment: What is the data type for CurrencyDate column? It should be  [DT_DBDATE].

Comment: yep doesn't work.. ive tried changing it to every date time data type there is and it still wont map..

Comment: Can you list the steps you are taking? I tried this and it works fine. In any case you can compare your package to the lesson package provided at this link - [Sample Package Download](http://msftisprodsamples.codeplex.com/downloads/get/596031)

Comment: Hi Amit, I am following the steps in the tutorial on the msdn site. The package I downloaded didn't have the Dim.Time table but rather has the Dim.Date table. Does it have something to do with that?

Comment: You are right. It has to be `DimDate`. I was looking at the lesson for different version.

Answer (score 0):

The FullDateAlternateKey in the DimDate SQL table has a type of [DT_WSTR] so I changed the type of the CurrencyDate to [DT_WSTR] instead of [DT_DBDATE] to match that type and I was able to map them fine.

Answer (score 0):

Added conversion and it worked, but recreated the flat file manager connection again.

[image]